# Sprite disappears when key is pressed javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im currently working on getting my player sprite to move around my screen, but when a key is pressed all the sprite seems to do is disappear! I have no errors coming up in firebug, so i am assuming that the sprite isn't being redrawn correctly or something along those lines.

Here is my code for my player:

```
function Player()
 {
  var sprite = new Sprite(),
   player,
   x,
   y,
   w = sprite.width,
   h = sprite.height,
   speed = 4;


this.init_Player = function(pos_X, pos_Y){
  player = sprite.load("player");
   x = pos_X;
   y = pos_Y;
};

this.update = function(delta) {

    var calculated_speed = (speed * delta) * (60/1000);

    $(document).keydown(function(e)
    {
        var cancel_default = (e.which === 32 || (e.which > 36 && e.which < 41));
        cancel_default && e.preventDefault();

        if(e.keyCode == 37){
            x -=calculated_speed;
        }
        else if(e.keyCode == 38){
            y -=calculated_speed;
        }
        else if(e.keyCode == 39){
            x +=calculated_speed;
        }
        else if(e.keyCode == 40){
            y +=calculated_speed;
        }
    });



};

this.draw = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(player,x, y, w ,h);
};
 }
```

The player is created in my main game javascript file like so:

```
player.init_Player(location_X,location_Y);
```

And then in my main game loop i have the now, delta and last times being made as well as the call to player.update and player.render like so:

```
 function update(){

    now = Date.now();
    delta = now - last_update;

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    gameGUI.update();

    player.update(delta);
    player.draw();

    last_update = now;
    setTimeout(update,1);
 }
```

Like i said at the top, all my sprite does on a key press is disappear. The code you can see above is all the code i have for the player so somewhere in here is the bug!

How would i accomplish making my sprite move on screen with a time-based animation like the one i've set up?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Also to let you know, i have last_update equal to Date.now() the line before my update call gets made initially like so:

```
function game_init(state) {
    game_settings(state);
    last_update = Date.now();
    update();
}
```

**Edit 2**
On continued inspection, it doesn't seem like the sprite is disappearing after all, just moving very far e.i off the game screen... so another guess is that my calculations are wrong somewhere?

Comment: my guess is that last_update is 0 initially.  Your first delta is going to be huge (i.e. it will equal now) and cause offscreen drawing.

Comment: beware of typing errors. large written function name `Player` and call `player`

Comment: so whats the best way to fix this @SB ?

Comment: You could set last_update to now on the first go around - basically if last_update is zero, set it to now.  delta will be zero, and then after that you should be ok in your next loop.  Depends on what behavior you are looking for.

Comment: @codelio i constructed the file Player like so : <code>player = new Player();</code>

Comment: @SB so ive set last_update to equal Date.now() the line before the update is initially called, but no difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All sorted guys, i have my character moving using this little tutorial! Real easy to read and understand for the beginners out there.
[LINK](http://blog.cubicleninja.com/?cat=26&paged=6)

What do the pros think of this tutorial?